# Calcular precio total de un producto en una tabla jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image: Ventas Productos]

Hola mis amigos...tengo una consulta como puedo calcular el precio total si aumento el input de cantidad y/o coloco un descuento. Mediante jquery

Este es el código de la tabla

```
<table id="VerDetallePedido" class="table table-condensed dataTable" style="color: white;" role="grid">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 14px;">Id</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 109px;">Descripción</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 129px;">Cantidad</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 69px;">P. Unitario</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 130px;">Descuento</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 49px;">P. Total</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 9px;"></th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr><th colspan="5" style="text-align:right" rowspan="1">Total:</th><th id="tdTotal" rowspan="1" colspan="1"> S/.70.50</th></tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    <tbody><tr role="row" class="odd"><td>3</td><td>Toalla LP-Color Rojo</td><td><input name="cantidad" type="number" class"form-control"="" value="1" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtCantidad"></td><td>40.00</td><td><input name="descuento" type="text" class"form-control"="" value="0" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtDescuento"></td><td>40.00</td><td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger remover"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td>4</td><td>Tomatodo-Colo blanco</td><td><input name="cantidad" type="number" class"form-control"="" value="1" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtCantidad"></td><td>30.50</td><td><input name="descuento" type="text" class"form-control"="" value="0" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtDescuento"></td><td>30.50</td><td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger remover"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

En el jquery e usado la Api de Datatable.net para agregar las filas y para obtener valor del input y que se actualice la fila tengo este código

```
function AgregarGridDetallePagos(producto_Id) {

    var t = $('#VerDetallePedido').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        destroy: true,
        searching: false,
        select: { style: 'single' },
        footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column(5)
                .data()
                .reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            // Update footer
            $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                ' S/.' + (total).toFixed(2) + ''
            );

            $('#hdMonto').val(total);

        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'producto_Id': producto_Id },
        url: '/Merchadising/Get',
        success: function (msg) {

            t.row.add([
                msg.Id,
                msg.nombreProducto + '-' + msg.descripcionProducto,
                '<input name="cantidad" type="number" class"form-control" value="1" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtCantidad" />',
                (msg.precioVenta).toFixed(2),
                '<input name="descuento" type="text" class"form-control" value="0" style="color:black;  text-align:center;" id="txtDescuento" />',
                (msg.precioVenta).toFixed(2),
                '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger remover"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>'
            ]).draw(false);

            $('.remover').click(function () {
                t.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
            });

            $('#VerDetallePedido').on('input', ':input', function () {
                var value = $(this).val(); //obtiene el valor actual del input.
                var name = $(this).prop('name');
                if (value.length > 0) { //si el campo no esta vacio
                    console.log(name + ": " + value);


                }
            });


            notif({
                type: 'success',
                msg: 'Añadido correctamente.'
            });

        }

    });
}
```

Y como resultado obtengo esto:

[image: Resultado del codigo]

Comment: Deberías colocar el código que muestra esa pantalla, para poder ayudarte, sino, las respuestas serán muy amplias. Te recomiendo que leas [ask]

Comment: Exactamente, pon lo que has hecho hasta el momento para poder indicarte mejor.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta haber si me puedes ayudar :(